# Water cut off effect in UE4

Tags: shaders, unreal-4, water

Working on a side scroller game in **Unreal Engine 4** and I need to create a **water cut off effect** like seen in the screenshot of Ori and the Blind forest.

Basically need a side perspective on water bodies like lakes and ponds where I can see objects underwater as well as above water. Water may be subject to ripples and disturbances (caused by player or fish swimming in the water).

Thanks
[image: Water cut off effect in Ori and the Blind Forest]

Comment: Have you tried using 2 semi-transparent images, one for the surface, one for the underwater part? Objects can be drawn below them, as well as above them

Comment: Getting the horizontal water place is the easy part. However getting the vertical plane that we see from the side (the water against glass kind off effect) is what is eluding me cause the 2 planes need to in sync especially when there are ripples. Someone suggested to use the near clip plane but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to Antoine Louisia, his answer - "The mesh i used to create this water is a cube, and i added vertex color (G Channel) only on the top of this cube. This way, you get a mask that you may use for the displacement and the foam (not for the color), so it doesnt affect the sides of your cube. They may be a lot of other ways to achieve this, but this one works perfectly fine !"